# Bluetooth consistently turning itself off

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-6

I'm having issue where my bluetooth will occasionally turn off.  This is an issue because I have a smartwatch that connects with bluetooth.

My SO also has a smartwatch, but doesn't have this issue.  I noticed in my battery usage that Bluetooth shows up as an entry in my phone, but does not on my SO.

When I tap on bluetooth, there is an option for 'Adjust Power Use'.  It's apparently set to 'Turn off bluetooth when not in use.'  I can tap on this option, but all it does it take my to the Bluetooth pairing screen, which doesn't seem to have any way to change the option.  I also do not have battery saver mode on.  There's a variety of things that are battery optimized, but my list of apps matches my SO's phone as well, so I don't think that's an issue either.

Clearly I don't want my bluetooth to turn off, otherwise it makes my watch kind of useless.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried checking `logcat` output? The kernel prints out all sorts of messages. Some debug info would help us track the issue.

Comment: I haven't yet, no.  When it turns off is kind of random, so sitting and watching logcat isn't something I considered.

Answer (score 0):

So if you go into BATTERY> : MENU> BATTERY OPTIMIZATION> and change "NOT OPTIMIZED" to "ALL APPS", you can then select each app or service you want "NOT OPTIMIZED". Try Bluetooth Midi and Bluetooth Sharing to set Not Optimized.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

My phone had this problem, and I narrowed down the problem to be caused by the Fitbit app syncing to my Versa watch.

The "problem" was actually just a mis-configuration in Fitbit app related to the the bluetooth sync options.